# Property [articles] does not exist on this collection instance in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to create a navbar be `submenu` and give `path` of submenu.

when `{{ dd($menus) }}`

[menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rodGz.png)

when `dd($menu->getChild)`

[submenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rodGz.png)

My blade

```
  <ul>
    @foreach($menus as $menu)
        <li>
            {{ $menu->name_fa }}
            <ul>
                @foreach($menu->getChild->articles as $article)
                    <li>
                        {{ $article->title }}
                    </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </li>
    @endforeach
   </ul>
```

AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('*', function($view) {
        $view->with('menus', Category::with('articles')->whereParent_id(0)->get());
    });
}
```

Category.php

```
public function getChild ()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}

public function articles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
}
```

It has an error...

> Property [articles] does not exist on this collection instance

Comment: if the $menu is a instance of the Category model, then you should be able to retrieve the articles from the $menu variable:

```$menu->articles```

Comment: Ok , but I  want to create a submenu and a submenu has link

Comment: Do you understand the problem now? Can you help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, since you have a hasMany relationship, it should really be named `children` not `getChild` or `getChildren`.

Category.php

```
public function children ()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}

public function articles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
}
```

Assuming in your view composer you are loading the `$menus` variable with something like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('*', function($view) {
        $menus = Category::with(['articles', 'children.articles'])
                ->where('parent_id', 0)
                ->get();

        $view->with('menus',  $menus);
    });
}
```

Your issue is that you are using the not iterating over the children's articles correctly. You are attempting to access the articles from the collection not from the child category. Your blade should look like:

```
 <ul>
    @foreach($menus as $menu)
        <li>
            {{ $menu->name_fa }}
            <ul>
                @foreach($menu->children as $child)
                    @if($child)
                        @foreach($child->articles as $article)
                            <li>
                                {{ $article->title }}
                            </li>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </li>
    @endforeach
   </ul>
```

Comment: What is `$desiredIds`    [error][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lErw.png

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi look at updated answer. That code was there because you initially I did not notice the view composer in your question, so I was guessing how you were populating it.

Comment: I did not solve my problem, I did not see submenu and I see Menus

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi please share a dd of $menus in the view composer, and format it nicely, and place it in your actual question, not a link to a screenshot

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi "format it nicely, and place it in your actual question, not a link to a screenshot" I am not opening it.

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi Also, please do dd($menus->toArray()), it will be more relevant